# How does lodash allow the import of individual modules?

Tags: javascript, module, lodash

I am writing a very simple library and I want to be able to import the whole library or just specific modules.

The library is written in `ES6` but I'll be compiling it so that it works with commonjs, AMD etc...

I've cloned and built lodash but I just don't understand how they allow the import of individual modules. Their `/dist/` folder simply contains the entire library.

I've tried googling this with various different phrasings but I can't find any tutorial or article on how this is achieved.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried ```import map from 'lodash/map';``` should work

Comment: @dashton the lodash library is working fine. The issue is that I am trying to achieve this with my own library but I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

Comment: ok, you should add some code showing what you export and how you've tried to import it

Comment: Hi did you got the solution? if yes can you share with the community?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to allow users of your library to target specific functions of your library, node allows you to target files/folders in the import/require, so all you need to do is name your files in an understandable way:

```
myModule/
├── functionOne.js
└── mySubmodule/
    ├── index.js
    └── functionOfSub.js
```

You can import these individually:

```
// Targets myModule/functionOne.js
const functionOne = require('myModule/functionOne'); 
// Targets myModule/mySubmodule/index.js
const mySubmodule = require('myModule/mySubmodule');
// Targets myModule/mySubmodule/functionOfSub.js
const mySubmoduleFunction = require('myModule/mySubmodule/functionOfSub');
```